# Optimizing geometric dimensions of the stripline in AWR DE (Microwave Office) or similar software

Tags: rf, pcb-design, optimization

I'm designing a stripline step inductance to compensate the capacitive impedance. My goal is to minify the WSVR parameter of the port and I may vary the dimensions of the stripline (widths and length) but the sum of lengths must be constrained by one exact given value (I'm working on improvement of the part of existing plate and the remaining part is not to be changed). Here's the simplified example drawing.[image]

Is it possible in AWR Design Environment (former Microwave Office)? I know you can optimize absolute parameters but how about relative parameters? Currently I  manually tune these lengths and widths but I want to automate it.